# How to create columns from a string in a dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

WHAT I HAVE:

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'long string':'ha: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n hi: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n ho: (tra: 1 la: 2)'}, 
{'long string':'hi: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n ha: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n ho: (tra: 1 la: 2)'}, 
{'long string':'ho: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n hi: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n ha: (tra: 1 la: 2)'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
df
```

GIVES

```
    long string
0   ha: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n hi: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n ho...
1   hi: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n ha: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n ho...
2   ho: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n hi: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n ha...
```

WHAT I WANT

```
inp = {'ha-tra':['1', '1', '1'], 'ha-la':['2', '2', '2'], 'hi-tra':['1', '1', '1'], 'hi-la':['2', '2', '2'],'ho-tra':['1', '1', '1'], 'ho-la':['2', '2', '2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
df
```

GIVES

```
    ha-tra  ha-la   hi-tra  hi-la   ho-tra  ho-la
0   1       2       1       2       1       2
1   1       2       1       2       1       2
2   1       2       1       2       1       2
```

CONTEXT

From a large string, I want to get each combination of (ha hi ho) and (tra la), and get the scores related to those combinations from the string. The problem is that the order of (ha hi ho) is not similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ndf = (df["long string"]
         .str.extractall(r"(ha|hi|ho):\s\((?:tra|la):\s(\d+)\s(?:tra|la):\s(\d+)\)")
         .droplevel("match")
         .set_index(0, append=True)
         .set_axis(["tra", "la"], axis=1)
         .unstack()
         .swaplevel(axis=1))
ndf.columns = ndf.columns.map("-".join)
```

- Extract the desired parts with a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/F3EKrX/1)
- Drop the index level induced by `extractall` called `match`
- Append the `ha-hi-ho` matches as the index (`0` is first capturing group)
- Rename the remaining columns `tra` and `la`
- Unstack the `ha-hi-ho` index to the columns
- Swap the `ha-hi-ho` and `tra-la` levels' order in columns so that `ha-hi-ho` is upper
- Lastly join these levels of columns' names with a hyphen

to get

```
  ha-tra hi-tra ho-tra ha-la hi-la ho-la
0      1      1      1     2     2     2
1      1      1      1     2     2     2
2      1      1      1     2     2     2
```

Comment: This answer is perfect.

Follow up question for those interested: what if you have a lot more variables than (ha-ho-hi) but 52? They all have the following structure: PA0.01, PB0.02, PA0.03.

Comment: @Charles So the pattern is not the same as this question e.g, `PA: (tra: 0.01)`? If not, maybe you can ask another question and people may answer because it would be somewhat a different question than this.

Comment: Sorry yes the pattern is similar, only it would be 52 variants of ha/ho/hi and 4 variants of tra/la. An example would be "Sorted zone data list: ZoneData(zoneId=PA3.40, zoneLocationNumber=2672747, occupancyPercentage=61, numberOfHitsOnItemsFromTote=0, spurIsFull=false, isOnHold=false)\n" instead of "ha: (tra: 1 la: 2) \n"

Comment: @Charles I see, but you only want to extract certain fields, e.g., those that start with  `PA`? Also, can you please edit the question with these new samples and desired output?

Comment: I tuned this solution for my own one a little bit. If you are interested, the final regex became:
.str.extractall(r"(PA0.02|PB0.09|PB3.47|PA1.14|PB1.21|PA3.44|PB1.24|PB3.45|PB2.34|PA0.03|PA2.30|PA0.01|PB2.33|PA3.40|PA0.06|PB1.23|PB3.49|PB1.20|PB2.31|PA1.13|PA3.42|PA3.39|PA1.18|PB3.48|PB1.19|PB1.22|PB0.10|PA1.17|PA2.28|PA1.16|PA2.26|PA3.41|PA2.25|PA1.15|PA0.05|PA2.29|PB3.50|PB2.35|PB3.52|PB2.36|PB0.08|PB3.51|PB0.12|PB2.38|PA3.43|PB3.46|PA2.27|PB2.32|PB0.07|PA0.04|PB2.37),\s(?:zoneLocationNumber)=(\d+),\soccupancyPercentage=(\d+), numberOfHitsOnItemsFromTote=(\d+)")

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve:

```
df1 = (
    df['long string'].str.extractall(
        r'.*?([a-z]+)\s*?:\s*?\(([a-z]+):\s*(\d+)\s*([a-z]+):\s*(\d+)\)')
    .droplevel("match")
    .set_index(0, append=True)
)

d1 = df1.iloc[:, :2]
d2 = df1.iloc[:, 2:]
d2.columns = d1.columns

df2 = pd.concat([d1, d2]).reset_index()
df2 = df2.pivot(index='level_0', columns=[0, 1], values=2)
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('-'.join)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

ALTERNATIVE:

```
df2 = (
    (
        df['long string'].str.extractall(
            r'.*?([a-z]+)\s*?:\s*?\(([a-z]+):\s*(\d+)\s*([a-z]+):\s*(\d+)\)')
        .droplevel("match")
        .set_index(0, append=True)
        .apply(lambda x: x.values.reshape(-1, 2), axis=1)
        .explode()
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .add_prefix('val')
        .reset_index()
    ).pivot(index=['level_0'], columns=[0, 'val0'], values='val1')
).reset_index(drop=True)
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('-'.join)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  ha_la ha_tra hi_la hi_tra ho_la ho_tra
0     2      1     2      1     2      1
1     2      1     2      1     2      1
2     2      1     2      1     2      1
```